# Storing more than one value into Isolated Storage

Tags: c#, isolatedstorage

I have created a isolated storage that only store one values and display one value of e.g. `"aaaaaaaa,aaaaaaaa"`.
How can I make it so that it stores
1)`"aaaaaaaa,aaaaaaaaa"`
2)`"bbbbbbbb,bbbbbbbbb"`
3)`"cccccccccc,cccccccccc"`

Below shows codes that stores only one value:

```
//get the storage for your app 
IsolatedStorageFile store = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();
//define a StreamWriter
StreamWriter writeFile;

if (!store.DirectoryExists("SaveFolder"))
{
    //Create a directory folder
    store.CreateDirectory("SaveFolder");
    //Create a new file and use a StreamWriter to the store a new file in 
    //the directory we just created
    writeFile = new StreamWriter(new IsolatedStorageFileStream(
         "SaveFolder\\SavedFile.txt", 
         FileMode.CreateNew, 
         store));
}
else
{
    //Create a new file and use a StreamWriter to the store a new file in 
    //the directory we just created
    writeFile = new StreamWriter(new IsolatedStorageFileStream(
         "SaveFolder\\SavedFile.txt", 
         FileMode.Append, 
         store));
}

StringWriter str = new StringWriter();
str.Write(textBox1.Text);
str.Write(",");
str.Write(textBox2.Text);

writeFile.WriteLine(str.ToString());
writeFile.Close();

textBox1.Text = string.Empty;
textBox2.Text = string.Empty;

    StringWriter str = new StringWriter();
str.Write(textBox1.Text);
str.Write(",");
str.Write(textBox2.Text);


writeFile.WriteLine(str.ToString());
writeFile.Close();

textBox1.Text = string.Empty;
textBox2.Text = string.Empty;
```

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do - create a single file with multiple lines, or create multiple files.

Comment: single file with multiple lines, thanks for the correction.

Comment: Right, so call `WriteLine` multiple times, once per line...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `WriteLine` several times like below

```
writeFile.WriteLine(string.Format("{0},{1}", "aaaaa","aaaaa"));
writeFile.WriteLine(string.Format("{0},{1}", "bbbbb","bbbbb"));
writeFile.WriteLine(string.Format("{0},{1}", "ccccc","ccccc"));
```

Answer (score 1):

I can confirm Damith's answer, and should be marked as so.

If you're wondering about reading the lines back in:

```
IsolatedStorageFileStream stream = new IsolatedStorageFileStream("SaveFolder", FileMode.Open, store);

StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream);

string rdr = reader.ReadLine();
```

rdr will be a string representing the first line, you can then call `ReadLine()` again to get the next line, etc. The first call to `ReadLine()` will return the first line you wrote to the store.

Hope this is useful to you or anyone else working in this area.

Comment: yes this is helpful, may I know ReadLine rather than ReadToEnd, How can I get do a read line loop read line again then retrieve it.